# Failed to generate the schema for the JAX-B, only happens during CORS call to REST service

Tags: java, angularjs, web-services, rest, glassfish

I have developed a REST service/resource that runs in Glassfish 4 and have also developed a UI in AngularJS. When I deploy the UI code via a WAR file (along with the REST code) to Glassfish and test the access directly via a browser accessing the Glassfish application (http://localhost:8080) everything works as expected.

However, the strange thing is that when I deploy the UI code separately to a Tomcat server (running on port 8090), one of the GET requests (which returns a Response with a entity of type Map keyValues = new HashMap();...doesn't even access any of my entity classes) I get the following error in the Glassfish server log:

Severe: Failed to generate the schema for the JAX-B elements
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Property "salesOrderUid" has an XmlID annotation but its type is not String.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder.getSalesOrderUid()
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder
        at private business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrderLine.salesOrder
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrderLine
        at private java.util.List business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.CatalogItem.salesOrderLines
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.CatalogItem
        at private java.util.List business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item.catalogItems
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item
        at private business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.ProductCategoryItem.item
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.ProductCategoryItem
Class has two properties of the same name "salesOrderUid"
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public int business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder.getSalesOrderUid()
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder
        at private business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrderLine.salesOrder
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrderLine
        at private java.util.List business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.CatalogItem.salesOrderLines
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.CatalogItem
        at private java.util.List business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item.catalogItems
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item
        at private business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.ProductCategoryItem.item
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.ProductCategoryItem
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private int business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder.salesOrderUid
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder
        at private business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrder business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrderLine.salesOrder
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.SalesOrderLine
        at private java.util.List business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.CatalogItem.salesOrderLines
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.CatalogItem
        at private java.util.List business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item.catalogItems
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item
        at private business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.Item business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.ProductCategoryItem.item
        at business.salesOrderMgmt.entity.ProductCategoryItem

And in the Chrome console I get the following error (which I believe is misleading because I am setting the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header on the server side before the response object is returned to the client/requester.

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8090' is therefore not allowed access.

I believe the Chrome/client-side error is misleading because on the server-side I add a header to each response ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8090")...works for the other requests so why wouldn't it work for this one?

The oddest thing to me is that the REST resource method isn't accessing the entity classes that purportedly have the invalid id types. It is calling a service to calculate the taxes and shipping using parameters passed into it which represent the promotionCode, zipCode, and subTotal--no SalesOrder entity object is accessed.

There are two differences between this particular REST call and the others that are working:
1) This particular call passes parameters with the request whereas the others do not, and
2) This request filter detects HTTP Method (OPTIONS).

Note than on all of my REST resource methods I am including the following as a method parameter "resourceMethod(@QueryParam("callback") String callback, ....)".

Any ideas what might be causing these mysterious errors?

Comment: Is `salesOrderUid` a `String`. I think `@XmlID` is limited to usage with string types. See the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.html). Seems the error is complaining about the property not being a String.

Answer (score 4):

As I guessed, the errors were very misleading and not related to the issue. The browser was "pre-empting" the GET request with an OPTIONS request which was not returning expected information to the browser to indicate that the browser/client-side application may continue.

I had to do two things: 1) Catch the OPTIONS method in the Request Filter and set headers on the response, and 2) in the Response Filter set headers to allow for CORS as well as the methods and other headers...the code snippets follow:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RESTRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( RESTRequestFilter.class.getName() );

    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestCtx ) throws IOException {
        log.info( "Executing REST request filter" );
          requestCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
          requestCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8090");
          requestCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT" );
          requestCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type" );

        // When HttpMethod comes as OPTIONS, just acknowledge that it accepts...
        if ( requestCtx.getRequest().getMethod().equals( "OPTIONS" ) ) {
           log.info( "HTTP Method (OPTIONS) - Detected!" );

            // Just send a OK signal back to the browser (Abort the filter chain with a response.)
           Response response = Response.status( Response.Status.OK )
                   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
                   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8090")
                   .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, accept, headers")
                   .build();           
           requestCtx.abortWith( response );

        }

    }

}

@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RESTResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( RESTResponseFilter.class.getName() );

    @Override
    public void filter( ContainerRequestContext requestCtx, ContainerResponseContext responseCtx ) throws IOException {
        log.info( "Executing REST response filter" );

        // The following was required to permit testing outside the Application Server Container
//        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:53307" );
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8090");
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "OPTIONS, GET, POST, DELETE, PUT" );
        responseCtx.getHeaders().add( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With" );
    }
}
```